# How to set yarn application id in a PySpark app

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to find a way to create a custom application id for a pyspark app submitted via YARN on EMR.
Usually YARN application ids are in this format `application_1632776696096_0006`

Is there a way to modify them somehow to add a prefix or to make them completely custom?

Appreciate your response! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ApplicationId is a unique identifier generated internally by yarn,there is no way to customize it except modify the source code.
You can achieve the purpose of distinguishing apps by specifying appname. E.g:

```
spark-submit --name
```

Comment: Thanks for your response